# How to place an imageview on the top in android Studio?

Tags: android-layout, android-studio, imageview, android-imageview

As it's shown in the android studio it looks perfectly fine but whenever i run the app on my cell phone it looks like this  any idea ,please ?? [the app on the phone and the android studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hqyIO.jpg)

Comment: You've included a picture of your activity_inshaa_allah_hamster.xml . Please edit your question and post it as text so we can help you

Comment: can you paste your xml code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using Relative Layout.
First thing I noticed in your code is that you used margin buttom in Image view which is top of the screen already.So I suggest to not use Margin Buttom in that because relative layout bydefault keep that image on top .So i give you some idea to fix it.

1.)Image is on top so and its Relative layout.
    `<ImageView
             android:id="@id/image" (give any id here)
             android:src=""
             android:marginleft=""   ("Add ur dimensions")
             android:marginright=""
             android:adjustviewbound="True"/>`

2.)Next is Textview.

```
<TextView
        android:id="@id/text"
        android:text="Name:Lovely Hamester"
        android:layout_below="@+id/image"
        android:margintop=""/>
```

So the main thing i wanna point of is this "Id".Relative Layout directly cant put views line by line like Linear Layout,We need to give command to the view to where it need to place.So thats why we use "layout_below" which instruct Text view to stay after imageview.There are different commands also.Please check that,like "layout_rightof","layout_leftof".
    Just give id to every view and command them in Relative layout.Your other code is perfect.Dont use Margin Bottom , because it kept space from bottom which looks perfect in the preview but every Mobile have different size so thats why its not shows perfect in your screen.

Comment: Thank you so much ... the problem has been solved after adding this code : android:adjustviewbound="True"

Comment: Your Welcome :).Contact me anytime for android related questions

Answer (score 0):

just move code imageview to the top

example

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="600dp"
        android:src="@drawable/test"/>

    <ProgressBar
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:id="@+id/progressbar"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rv_notes"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:listitem="@layout/item_note"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab_add"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:src="@drawable/button"
        app:borderWidth="1dp"
        app:elevation="9dp"
        android:backgroundTint="#FFFFFF"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score -1):

The problem as i see it that you have a margin bottom override the layout align Parent Top so if you delete that and leave only :

```
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
```

also it is redundant to call align right and left and bottom , align top will be enough.

i'm sure it will work.

Comment: we need to addi the code : android:adjustviewbound="True" beside this one 
 android:layout_alignParentTop="True"  , thanks for help :D